# What is the time complexity of the SearchInWindow algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I wonder what the time complexity of the following algorithm is.

```
function SearchInWindow(p)
        for l ← 1 ... L do
                c_l ← CountOccurrences(p, l)
        end for
end function
```

The `CountOccurrences` returns the number of occurrences of a fragment of the length `l` positioned at the position `p` in the window `(p + 1 ... p + W − 1)`, where `W` is the window length.

The `CountOccurrences` is in *O(l × W)*. The `p` is the pointer to the data and should not affect the time complexity.

My guess is `binom(L+1, 2) × W`. But here I am not at all sure.

Comment: What's the time complexity of `CountOccurrences`? For `CountOccurrences(a, b)`, is it `O(a)`?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `p`? Alternatively, what range of values can `p` take?

Comment: The `CountOccurrences` is in _O(l × W)_. The `p` is the pointer to the data and should not affect the time complexity.

Comment: OK. I have had some time to think about it and I'll write you an answer.

Comment: I also suggest you edit that information you just gave me into the question, as it is important to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the time complexity.

`CountOccurrences` takes a parameter `l` (and also `p`, but as it does not affect the time complexity, we will disregard it), and complete in `O(l × W)`.

You're running a loop from `1` to `L` and calling `CountOccurences` with each value.

The time complexity of that is:

`O(1 × W) + O(2 × W) + O(3 × W) + ... + O(L × W)`
`= O(W × (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + L))` 
`= O(W × 1/2 × (L²+L)`

Note that we can disregard the constant. Additionally, `L² >> L`, so `O(L²+L)` = `O(L²)`.

So we have: `= O(W × L²)` as the final answer.

---

Note: Your answer of `binom(L+1, 2) × W` given in the question is technically equivalent as my answer, but since `2` in `binom(L+1, 2)` is a constant, we can simplify it further.